# Designing MySQL table for Achievements system

Tags: c++, mysql

I am creating a database for an achievement system (like something you would see in a Blizzard game). I would like to have a GUI that displays the current progress of all achievements in the game which means I will need to query the progress of all achievements for a user in order to populate the GUI. I plan on having somewhere around 100 achievements.

This brings about a design question. **What is the best way to design the database and querying code to query the progress of ~100 bit fields?**

It seems like the brute force method would be to get the entire row of achievements and then for each field in the row do some hardcoded string comparison to determine which achievement we are dealing with.

Another possible solution may be to have a big switch statement based on the column index of the table and handle each achievement for each case (requires not modifying the table or you have to refactor a lot of C++ code).

I'm curious to hear any other designs you guys may have for this.
Thanks!

Comment: What about something like `users -< user_achievements >- achievements`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that (sorry I'm still a bit of a MySQL noob). Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest building a solution using 3 tables. These tables are users, achievements and user_achievements. A user would be identified with a u_id in the users table. An achievement would be identified with a a_id in the achievements table. You would then keep track of users achievements by inserting a row in the user_achievements table that includes a u_id to identify the user and a a_id to identify the achievement. The user_achievements table would also contain a column that would specify the % completion of that achievement for the given user.

Comment: This is an interesting design. It keeps the data smaller since we don't have a bunch of 0's for each user and each achievement. What seems like the down side is that in order to determine which achievements a user has earned requires finding each row with a certain u_id instead of finding one row with the u_id and parsing all of the columns. Would this cause a performance penalty?

Comment: You would use joins for that. The schema I propose is in what's called normalized form. There's a lot of benefits associated with it and the performance penalty is usually not significant unless you're dealing with say > 1TB of data.

Comment: I see. I'm going to read up on normalized form and joins. It is still not clear to me how using joins could optimize this design. Thanks for all of the information good sir.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question and even though it's 5 years old, perhaps someone would be interested in following approach.

- Achievements are usually broken down to numbers (the rest, like Name, Description of each achievement can be put to site/app core to avoid bloating the DB).
- lets be simple, we are not FB and don't need separate table for them, so in "users" table we add just 1 single column: "Achievements" it is a varchar(50). Number in brackets (50) will depend on your actual needs to this column (i.e. how much data it stores).
- so you end up having in each cell of the Achievements column a numerical sequence: 10982039482084109384

Read this line of digits as follows, from left to right: user has reached "1098 profile views", received "2039 likes", etc. Optionally, add a separator for easier distinction + to instantly handle cases when as first user had 25 likes, then 125, then 2039 (2 digits, 3 digits, 4 digits - or another alternative is to use 0025 then 0125 then 2039 given you know max digits is 4 per achievement). But still lets say we decide to use separators, i.e. a comma:

```
1098,2039,4820,8410,9384
```

Then once you need a data, just SELECT achievements belonging to specific userID and subsequently (if you added a separator)

```
explode (',', $array)
```

then your site php core knows  that first 4 digits stand for "profile views" and lets say this means that he has a level 10 badge for profile views (1 badge for 100 views).

Thereon, you can easily do operations with no further need for SQL queries. Example, user wants to know his progress on achieving a level 20 badge, you display: he has a 1098/2000 (or 55%) progress.

At that, achievement Description, Name, level information is stored in site core, while percentage is calculated on the go.

Hope the logic is clear and may be useful to any1 in community out there.

Cheers!