# Best MySQL datatype for "Achievements" column

Tags: php, mysql

With similar questions asked before (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292485/designing-mysql-table-for-achievements-system)), I have concluded:

- no need to separate "Achievements" data from "users" table into a separate table, unless you are FB. This helps avoiding unneded JOINs.
- we can think of "Achievements" data as numerical sequence (see below), so no need to make multiple columns (in "users" table) also.

Following this logic, I got a varchar(24) "Achievements" column in "users" table. Format:

```
1,4,50,300,50
```

USER class knows that 1 stands for: "1 posts written", 4 stands for "4 questions answered", etc. To get achievement data I use:

```
SELECT column's respective row BY userID
```

+

```
explode (',', $array);
```

I am thinking on whether varchar(24) is best choice for that purpose (say, there are 5 achievements totally, each max 4 digits + comma after, making max length of varchar24).

I understand that even if I put varchar(200) its OK - my table is relatively small compared to internet giants.

But desire for perfection does not let me be people and I am looking for your advise and expertise! =)

Comment: My advice would be use a NoSQL db and avoid all the issues you are trying to work around

Comment: You could also use the [JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: `no need to separate "Achievements" data from "users" table into a separate table, unless you are FB. This helps avoiding unneded JOINs.` But also causes additional problems, like when you decide you want to record the achievement date, or want to get a list of users who have achieved 50.... normalization isn't just for large volume data companies like Facebook, it makes sense even for small companies or simple websites, and the code to unpick data when you don't want to use joins can often make even small sites harder to manage and test, and adversely affect performance

Comment: I find it hilarious how you concluded that you shouldn't use the database the way it was designed to be used (data modelling, JOIN'ing data structures into meaningful information etc.) and you came up with the worst possible idea - storing comma separated lists as strings. And this guy that suggests NoSQL is just sugar on top, let's simply swap out entire software you're using and sprinkle it with something else that does the job worse than an actual database is. Please.. doubt everything. All the time.

Comment: @MarkBaker honestly, no problem I can see with recording in a date - please refer to my comment below under answer of Code.IT. Please also note I am not talking about industry all-case-best-practice, I am looking for good realization where I got like 5-6 achievements that are strictly numerical and may be easily put in a line 1,4,50,300,50. Why in the world would I need a separate table for that? I think one has to treat  best practices with certain self-estimate of the situation: when its simple, no point in making in hard

Comment: @Zerussian Clearly you know best, so you didn't really need to ask us for advice here at all.... but when we offer advice, it isn't simply because it's considered "best practice" regardless of circumstance.... it's because we spend so many hours here picking up the pieces and trying to fix things when people have taken a bad approach (as I consider you are doing).... you're dismissing normalization "unless you are FB", even though I've cited two possible situations that make it sensible for any project no matter how big or small.... when your "simple" approach becomes incredibly hard

Comment: If you just wanted people to validate that your approach is right, then don't ask....... you say you're asking because of a "desire for perfection" and "looking for your advise and expertise", then actually listen to the advice that you're being given

Comment: `Why in the world would I need a separate table for that` - because you are using **relational database** which stores **data** and **relations** and it uses a data structure called **table** to let you query the data AND relations between data. That's why you create a separate table. That's why you use the database in the first place. You simply do not understand this part of technology. And that's just fine, a lot of people don't understand RDBMS. What's not fine is REFUSING to listen to reason and going on about your way. No, your approach is horrible. Mark is absolutely correct.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, so stop jumping to conclusions. I didn't ask you to follow my advice blindly; I cited several examples to indicate why your "solution" was not a good solution. I am aware of other opinions, and indicated that I disagreed with yours, and why. And I'm not the person that got super-defensive when people didn't endorse what I was doing, that was you.

Answer (score 3):

I think to solve it like this is not "Best practise". The achievements and the users are connected with a **n:m** relationship.
See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

This needs you to create a relation table which has a foreign key for user and a foreign key for achievement. This table is used to create the connection between those tables.
That would be best practise.

In your way you will always be limited to the number of columns you have. Also when creating new columns the database will get to slow for actual use. You can try to save it as a CLOB (character large object) and write down a list of technical keys for achievements, which are separated by lines. But as I mentioned thats to complicated for the actual task.

A select statement in native sql for MySQL can look like:

```
SELECT USER.*, ACHIEVEMENT.* FROM USER_ACHIEVEMENT 
INNER JOIN USER ON USER.ID = USER_ACHIEVEMENT.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN ACHIEVEMENT ON ACHIEVEMENT.ID = USER_ACHIEVEMENT.ACHIEVEMENT_ID
```

> USER_ACHIEVEMENT : Is the table which connects USER and ACHIEVEMENT.

Note: It's not recommended to use * in sql selects

Comment: Well first of, I am talking about only 1 column containing numerical data, so no "when creating new columns" like you stated. Secondly, line is segregated by commas, so anytime I may add further details like date in format 20170802 (i know now that I will not need this). But think of the benefits: I do 1 separate func GetAchievements($id), containing 3 lines: (1) fast query SELECT Achievements WHERE userID=:user_id, (2) user_id = $id, and (3) explode array. That is it - I got all required data for each case I need to get the achievement. Fast. Simple. Comments?

Comment: The way you are doing this has not really benefits. It's just a workaround for something which can be solved much easier. Have you every heard of an entity-relationship-diagram? Maybe you should start learning how to create a right database architecture first before raping systems. Also you can't just say you will never need something, because you will never know what future will be like. So do consider the KISS concept.

Comment: Imagine if you change an achievement name/key or delete it or add a new one everyone is getting because he logged in 2 days ago. It's not really maintainable

Comment: So do you thin writing a functions to parse out numbers is faster than indexing a database table on number columns ?

Comment: Or a select statement with parsing function to get every user which has achieved achievement=500

Comment: How can you think billions of people which rely on JOINs are wrong, because a single cell is better for a relational-database ?

Comment: @Code.IT he thinks that because he's unable to utilize learned knowledge to come up with conclusions. I always find it fascinating how people think about table data structure as something they visualize and then they deduce it's "better" to store everything in a cell instead of in a relation. I sincerely wish you all the best in your endeavours Pavel, but the way you started with this - it doesn't look good. You have the wrong notion of what a table actually is. And no, it's not the thing that's rendered to you on the screen.